# “Accepted a friend” action visibility

Tags: facebook

On Facebook, if I hide the fact/entry that I have “accepted a friend,” will that also hide that fact on their recent activity too? Or will that friend also have to hide the fact that we just became friends too?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to have control over another account. Your friend has to hide it too.

Answer (score 1):

The story is separate on their time line, and your hiding it from your time line will not remove it from theirs.